# SQL Pivot Query

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot-table

I have the below data in SQL:
[image]

Now, I would like to pivot it base on the "CostCenterNumber" field to obtain this:
[image]

Comment: have you tried something at least???

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
DECLARE @cols as varchar(max)
DECLARE @sql as varchar(max)

SELECT @cols  = coalesce(@cols  + ',','') + '[' + CostCenterNumber + ']' FROM #MyTable

SET @sql = 
     'SELECT Year, GLClass, Code, GLDescription, ' + @cols + '
       FROM (
             SELECT *
             FROM #MyTable
             ) as P
       PIVOT 
             (
             SUM(Total)FOR [CostCenterNumber] IN (' + @cols + ')
             )AS pvt'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use  `where` and `between` condition from your query